# jquery submit form once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a custom magento module and i've got it all complete and working perfectly except one problem.

The module is a form with 4 radio buttons. They are all blank on the checkout page and I have them set up so that when you click one it submits the form and reloads the cart page with the "additional fees" in the subtotal.

My problem is that I need the first option to "auto submit" on page load. But I've tried ALOT of different things and can't come up with a way to use the jquery .submit() function to ONLY submit the form once. as it is now it works how I want it, except it loads the page in an endless loop.

Any way to say submit() only once?

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form to itself? If you submit the form to the different page, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set the default radio button server-side rather than having an extra submit/refresh cycle, but if you insist on doing it client-side...

I assume on subsequent refreshes the previous selection will be retained (because your server-side code echoes back the previously selected values?), so can you perhaps test whether any radios are checked and if not assume that that is the first and only time to auto-submit?

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var $radios = $('#yourFormId input[name="yourRadioButtonGroupName"]');

    if (!$radios.is(":checked")) {
       // No radios currently checked, so check the first and submit
       $radios.eq(0).prop("checked",true);
       $("#yourFormId").submit();
    }
});
```

The [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will "Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return `true` if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments."

Comment: You're welcome. (And sorry, I just noticed I left the crucial `!` out of the `if` condition, so I've edited that in...)